# About the use of bibliography for Cambridge university template

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I wrote the code for the bibliography:

```
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{xyz.bib}
\printbibliography
```

But the "Reference Section" is disappear. How I can write Reference Section?

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please add a Minimal Working Example to your question.

Comment: Does your code contain `\cite`-like directives? Did you run `biber` inbetween LaTeX runs? If so, did you get any error and/or warning messages? What do the messages say?

Comment: Yes, my code contains \cite directives. No, I don't know about this because I have use the template only and did the changes in the main file.

Comment: `biber` is an external program that collects information from the `\cite` directives and the `\addbibresource` command to build the formatted bibliography. I you don't run `biber` inbetween LaTeX runs, no bibliography will be built. The template file you're using may or may not contain a mention of the fact that it's essential to run `biber`.

Comment: With that code you will definitely need to run Biber on your document. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864 for background and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864 for help with setting you editor up to run Biber for you. I should mention that some templates already hard-code citation and bibliography packages (which may or may not be incompatible with `biblatex`), so check for any errors or warnings you might get.